# Is it possible to compile C++ code to .exe on a Mac?

Tags: c++, macos, terminal, g++, exe

I bought a pre-owned Macbook a little while ago and I've been coding inside Sublime Text 2 and compiling in Terminal with g++*. I wrote a stupid text adventure that I'd like to send to a friend and if possible, I'd like to know if there are any methods available on Mac of compiling to exe similar to the way I've been compiling my code (i.e. solely with terminal).

I understand that the easy solution would be to just compile the .cpp file on a Windows computer but my computer is all the way over at the other side of the room.

Thanks.

*Doing this due to being on Snow Leopard and being too tight to buy OSX Lion or an Apple developer license to access Xcode. If anyone has encountered the same problem then I found this solution on here ( https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer and http://cims.clayton.edu/csci1301/how_to/compiling_c_on_a_mac.htm). Allows you circumvent the bullshit of Apple.

Comment: What have you tried? Check cross-compilation in Google. This question contains a lot of irrelevant information.

Comment: Unnecessary snarkiness.  You can download Xcode 4.2 (and 3.2.6) for Snow Leopard with a free Apple developer account.

Comment: You don't need a developer 'license' to get Xcode. Xcode is free (except for one version of Xcode on Snow Leopard which at one point cost $5 in the App Store). Although Xcode doesn't directly support cross compiling to Windows.

Comment: It's unfortunate that your computer is at the other side of the room. If only there were a way to connect computers to each other using some kind of wires (or maybe, in the distant future, radio waves!) and teleport things from one to the other. I've heard about "sticks" that you can plug into computers and use as a kind of carrying case for computer digits, but that's probably just rumours.

Comment: This is a good question and you certainly didn't deserve a -7 vote.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin yeah.. it's not THAT stupid..

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is possible and it's known as cross-compilation.  Besides building your own toolchain for doing this, you can use MinGW: [Cross compiling with MinGW](http://crossgcc.rts-software.org/doku.php#compiling_for_win32_on_mac_os_x)